# Linking to matlab libraries in Eclipse (C++) for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, matlab, g++

I've code generated a simulink model into C code and written a C++ framework around it. It works well on windows, but now I want to compile it in a linux environment to be able to run it on a linux cluster (without using a windows emulator). I've set it up in Eclipse CDT on a cluster node, and I've added all the linker settings to the best of my knowledge, but when I try to compile I get linking errors.

The final compiler command is on the form (example for the libmex.so matlab library)

```
g++ -L{path to Matlab/bin/glnxa64} -o VCTSClient -lmex
```

However there are a large number of libraries linked, so I can't paste the whole thing.

Most of the libraries work fine, but some do not. The complete error message reads:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/.../bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/.../bin/ld: cannot find -ltbb
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/.../bin/ld: cannot find -ltbbmalloc
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/.../bin/ld: cannot find -licuuc
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/.../bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/.../bin/ld: cannot find -licudata
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/.../bin/ld: cannot find -licuil8n
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/.../bin/ld: cannot find -licuio
```

For some reason these can't be found, even though I successfully (as far as I know) link to other libraries in the same directory - for example the libmex.so mentioned above.

How do I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the source of your problem but did you try generating the model from Matlab running on Linux? I didn't use Matlab on Linux but it's possible that it doesn't generate the same code between the Linux and Windows version. That can explain why you're getting linkage errors.